# Editing keystone.js in anyway at all results in jshint "Path must be a string" + Aborted due to warnings

Tags: node.js, yeoman, jshint, yeoman-generator, keystonejs

After generating a 'yo keystone' build, I started following this tutorial:

http://www.tutorialindustry.com/keystonejs-cms-tutorial-for-beginners

And I tried changing the favicon path from public/favicon.ico to public/images/favicon.ico and jshint throws:

```
>> File "keystone.js" changed.
```

Running "jshint:server" (jshint) task
Warning: Path must be a string. Received { toString: [Function], reporter: [Function] } Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

I tried stepping back to undue my change and everytime, grunt watch yields the same error. I'm a newb at the node stack and still figuring out how all the pieces go together and have searched and searched for a solution to this, so any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Should probably open a bug report on `generator-keystone`

Comment: Ok. Will do. Thanks.